# select last item from a jquery class selection (if there are many)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm doing a simple class selection like this:

```
var myItem = $("#div-id h3.class-name");
```

this selection used to return just one item, but I added some code that may add more elements which has such class name. I would like to put in the variable the value of the only item (if there's one) or of the last (if it has many).

I've tried this but I get an error which says that length() is not a function.

```
var myItem = $("#div-id h3.class-name");    
if (myItem.length() > 0){
              myItem = myItem.last();
              console.log("it has multiple items");
    }
```

Can you help me understand how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use the `:last` selector? `let myItem = $('#div-id h3.class-name:last');`

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: True that `length() is not a function.` It is a property. Your code works fine without the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#test:last").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id="test">This is a heading</h2>

<p id="test">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```